# How is Microsoft's iOS bridge IslandWood implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, win-universal-app, windows-10

Microsoft's newly announced [Project Islandwood](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/uwp-bridges/project-islandwood) is interesting, as it allows Objective-C code written for iOS to be repurposed into a Universal Windows app.

I couldn't find any information on the details, so:

- Has Microsoft effectively implemented an iOS subsystem in Windows 10?
- Is it built on existing software (e.g. the old OpenStep source code) or built from scratch?
- Are all the various iOS frameworks - Core Data, Core Text, Core Graphics, OpenGl, etc - implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows writing Universal Windows Apps in Objective-C using the normal Windows Runtime along with an iOS API compat layer.

Visual Studio 2015 has a language projection for Objective-C so that you can compile Objective-C into a Windows app. The most common iOS API (CoreGraphics, CoreText, OpenGL, etc.) are provided .

You can import an Xcode project into Visual Studio and then compile it as a Windows app.

See the Project Islandwood site at http://aka.ms/islandwood and the Build talk [Compiling Objective-C Using the Visual Studio 2015 C++ Code Generation that Builds Windows, SQL, .Net, and Office](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-610) for details. Jim Radigan talks about the Objective C code generation in the first half. Salmaan Ahmed starts talking specifically about Project Islandwood about 33 minutes in.

Comment: About the iOS API compat layer - is this built on existing open source code (see my second question)? I'm trying to wrap my head around whether this was a moderate undertaking or something much larger. Also, is UIKit implemented?

Comment: The video has a question about how UIKit is implemented (around 58:45). The ios "emulator" is backed by DirectX.